# How to iterate Set elements using Struts 2 tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags, ognl

I have two `Set`s

```
set1  contains("A","B","C","D") elements
set2  contains("E","F","D","G") elements
```

I want to compare every element of `set1` with every element of `set2` and display matched elements using Struts2 tags.

Comment: What are you going to do after you've compared them?

Comment: Wow 3+ answers using two iterators. How about using single iterator anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
<s:iterator var="val1" value="set1">
 <s:iterator var="val2" value="set2">
  <s:if test="#val1 == #val2">
   <s:property /><br>
  </s:if>
 </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rearranged to better list the several ways:

1. With two [`Iterator`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html)s:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="setOne" var="first" status="ctr1">
       <s:iterator value="setTwo" var="second" status="ctr2">
           <s:if test="%{#first == #second}">
               Common value detected : [<s:property value="%{#first}"/>]
               <br/> setOne position : [<s:property value="%{#ctr1.index}"/>] 
               <br/> setTwo position : [<s:property value="%{#ctr2.index}"/>]
               <br/>
           </s:if>
       </s:iterator>
   </s:iterator>
   ```
2. With a single Iterator and [Set.contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

   ```
   <s:iterator value="setOne" var="first" status="ctr1">
       <s:if test="%{setTwo.contains('#first')}">
           Common value detected : [<s:property value="%{#first}"/>] <br/>
       </s:if>
   </s:iterator>
   ```
3. With a single Iterator and pure OGNL:

   ```
   <s:iterator value="setOne" var="first" status="ctr1">
       <s:if test="%{#first in setTwo}">
           Common value detected : [<s:property value="%{#first}"/>] <br/>
       </s:if>
   </s:iterator>
   ```
4. Without Iterators, using [OGNL List Selection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) only (thanks to @AleksandrM for the code):

   ```
   <s:property value="setOne.{? #this in setTwo}"/>
   ```

Comment: And how about w/o using iterator tag at all? :)

Comment: You mean with list projection ? Go ahead, upvote is pending :D

Comment: Actually with *selection* `<s:property value="f.{? #this in s}"/>`. ;)

Comment: Nice... but you should have put that as an answer. Future visitors will hardly read all the comments and that's interesting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.i think it will work for you. and if not then do some trial & error on this.

```
<s:iterator value="set1" var="first">
  <s:iterator value="set2" var="second">

   <s:set name="valueofset1" value="%{#set1.index}" />  
   <s:set name="valueOfSet2" value="%{#set2.index}" />  

     <s:if test="valueofset1 == valueOfSet2">
      //Do what ever you want
     </s:if>

  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```