# difficulty using nested iterator using two different array lists

Tags: arraylist, struts2, iterator, nested

This is satish...I am new to Struts2. I am developing forum application which uses 2 array list that are following:
1) public ArrayList forumData = new ArrayList<>();
2) public ArrayList replyList=new ArrayList<>();
above both arraylist in same class that is forumAction.

Now, in forumData list I stored all posts data along with postid and similar way in replyList I stored all replys with postid.
Now I want to iterate like a nested loop .here forumData's postid match with replyList's post id if match then display reply.

i want to display like:

post1:
        reply1
        reply2
post2
        reply1
        reply2

### Following is my code:

**forumAction.jsp**

```
//for post data
private String message;
private String post_title;
private String post_detail;
private String ctime;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String orgname;
private String country;
private String uimage;
private int post_id;


//for reply data
private int reply_id;
private String reply_desc;
private String rtime;
private String rfname;
private String rlname;
private String rorgname;
private String rcountry;
private String ruimage;
private int rpostid;
    public ArrayList<forumAction> lst = new ArrayList<>();
     public ArrayList<forumAction> replyList=new ArrayList<>();
//getter and setter done <br/>
// i called this function when my viewForum link will be clicked

public String viewForum() {
    try {

        this.openConncection();


        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from forum_post");

        while (rs.next()) {
            forumAction f=new forumAction();

            Statement ntst1=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsnt1=ntst1.executeQuery("select firstname,lastname,orgname,country,user_image from user where userid="+ rs.getString(2));
            while(rsnt1.next()){
                f.setFname(rsnt1.getString(1));
                f.setLname(rsnt1.getString(2));
                f.setOrgname(rsnt1.getString(3));
                f.setCountry(rsnt1.getString(4));
                f.setUimage(rsnt1.getString(5));
            }

            f.setPost_id(rs.getInt(1));
            f.setPost_title(rs.getString(3));
            f.setPost_detail(rs.getString(4));
            f.setCtime(rs.getString(5));
            lst.add(f);

        }

        //Get all reply data
        Statement ntst3=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsnt3=ntst3.executeQuery("select * from forum_reply");
        while(rsnt3.next()){
            System.out.println(rsnt3.getString(4));
            forumAction reply=new forumAction();

            Statement ntst4=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsnt4=ntst4.executeQuery("select firstname,lastname,orgname,country,user_image from user where userid="+ rsnt3.getString(2));
            while(rsnt4.next()){
                reply.setRfname(rsnt4.getString(1));
                reply.setRlname(rsnt4.getString(2));
                reply.setRorgname(rsnt4.getString(3));
                reply.setRcountry(rsnt4.getString(4));
                reply.setRuimage(rsnt4.getString(5));
            }

            reply.setReply_id(rsnt3.getInt(1));
            reply.setRpostid(rsnt3.getInt(3));
            reply.setReply_desc(rsnt3.getString(4));
            reply.setRtime(rsnt3.getString(5));

            replyList.add(reply);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return SUCCESS;
}
```

**viewforum.jsp**

```
<div id="forum>
        //first iterator for post data
       <s:iterator value="lst">
             <s:property value="post_title" />
             <s:property value="post_detail" />
                    //second iterator for reply data
                     <s:iterator value="replyList">
                           //if first iterator postid and this reply postid is same
                           <s:if test="post_id == rpostid">
                                      <s:property value="reply_desc" />
                            </s:if>
                     </s:iterator>
       </s:iterator>
</div>
```

....
I try a lot. but I not find the correct way.

Comment: Post a code you have tried. If you have a lot of code, choose the relevant one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070171/1654265

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <s:if test="lst.size() >0">
        <s:if test="replyList.size() > 0">
            <s:iterator value="lst" status="lst_status">
                <s:property value="lst.get(#lst_status).getPostTitle()" />
                <s:property value="lst.get(#lst_status).getPostDetail()" />
                <s:iterator value="replyList" status="replyList_status">
                    <s:if test="lst.get(#lst_status).getPostId() == replyList.get(#replyList_status).getRpostid()">
                        <s:property value="reply_desc" />
                    </s:if>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
    </s:if>
```