# Iterator within an iterator using Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, iterator

I have an iterator within an iterator, the second iterator needs to use the value of the list that the first iterator is iterating over as a parameter of a method call within iterator two. I cannot find the sufficient documentation that will show me what I need to use.

```
//firstList = "1","2","3","4";
<s:iterator value="firstList">
  <s:iterator value="getSecondList(FIRST LIST ITERATION PROPERTY REQUIRED HERE)">
    //Do Something
  </s:iterator>
<s:iterator>
```

I want to use `<s:property/>` but I cant use a struts tag inside a struts tag.
Thank you for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer as soon as posting, it took me ages but it just goes to show to only ask when exacerbated all other routes.

Using the var:

```
//firstList = "1","2","3","4";
<s:iterator value="firstList" var="parent">
  <s:iterator value="getSecondList(#parent)">
    //Do Something
  </s:iterator>
<s:iterator>
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way. There are several other ways to access the value of the iterated element (top, iteratorstatus, ognl,...), you may want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070171/1654265).